# JSON valid format in php

Tags: php, json

I'm processing a lot of json files but some of them have invalid format.

Is there a library to find a JSON format error?

I want error messages like: "Found error line 100 after {"property":val{" to easily find the line and fix it manually.

Each json file has 500+ lines.

Comment: Seems the error you see is telling you exactly where the error is..

Comment: @MartinKonecny I have a lot of type of format errors like a value with carriage return, or invalid quoted string, etc...

Comment: You will probably need to fix those manually :(

Comment: Exactly! but I need to know the line number to fix it quickly, the json files have 500+ lines.

Comment: What are you using to process these files? Which language?

Comment: It says it's on line 100

Comment: @Martin He doesnt have that now, thats what he wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a library to find a JSON format error?

You can try to use a PHP tool like [JSON Lint](https://github.com/Seldaek/jsonlint). Here is example usage in PHP:

```
use Seld\JsonLint\JsonParser;

$parser = new JsonParser();

// returns null if it's valid json, or a ParsingException object.
$parser->lint($json);

// Call getMessage() on the exception object to get
// a well formatted error message error like this

// Parse error on line 2:
// ... "key": "value"    "numbers": [1, 2, 3]
// ----------------------^
// Expected one of: 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']'

// Call getDetails() on the exception to get more info.

// returns parsed json, like json_decode() does, but slower, throws
// exceptions on failure.
$parser->parse($json);
```